# loop inside a loop with different mysql in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, loops

Objective: We need that it find registered people and shows which countries had visited like [In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltpWv.png)

We need to make a loop that creates php objects (The artists), with its own classes. This objetcs will come from a DataBase (mysql). For each of this objects, we need that it looks in the DataBase which rows are related with it (countries), and make it an php objetc too, with its own classes (Its own design with CSS, HTML)

We already tryed Angular with ng-bind-html so it could read HTML tags and its CSSs, but it only took the first loop, and the second one just didn't appeard. We tryed *while* inside another *while*, but I don't know what happens, but it only takes the first one.

The idea to make a loop this way is to hide countries while the user doesn't want to see them. If they click on the artist name, it will shows up the countries. But this is another story, we think we will use CSS for that.

I'll put the code I tryed to use for Angular, just in case someone have an idea with Angular.js.

Thank you very much for reading this. Best Wishes and Best Regards !

```html
    $data;
    $data['info'] = "";
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    if (isset($_POST['id'])){
   $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=ec;host=localhost;port=3306';
   $user = 'root';
   $password = '';
   $options = array(
       PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
   );

   try {
        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);   } catch (PDOException $e) {
       echo 'Fallo conexión: '. $e->getMessage();
   }

    $sql = "SELECT ....WHERE artist.artist_id = $i"; //This is to call only artist that the user actually have access to see.

    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    while($row = $query->fetch()){
        $artists[] = $row;
    };
        if (isset($artists)){

// 1- This is the First loop, it looks for the artist. This is working, barely.

        foreach($artists as $art) {   
       $a = $art['artist_id']
       $data['info'] .= "<div class='Main'>
           <div class='MainResult'>
               {$art['artist_name']}
           </div>
           <div>
             
           <div class='VisitedPlaces'>
                     <?php
                     $sql='SELECT country_name, country_city, country_time FROM country JOIN ...... WHERE... = $a';
                     $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
                     $query->execute();

// 2- Here's the second loop, that look for the countries related to the artist. The idea is that once it finish, look for the next artist in the first loop. This one don't works.

                         while($row = $query->fetch()){
                             $country = $row['country_name'];
                             $city = $row['country_city'];
                             $time = $row['country_time'];
                             echo '<div class="rslt">
                                     <h2>'.$country.'</h2>
                                     <span>'.$city.'</span>
                                     <span>'.$time.'</span>
                                   </div>';
                         };
                     ?>
           </div>        
       </div>";
   }
        echo JSON_encode($data);
    }
```

Comment: Your outer loop is building up a string that is a property of your `$data` object that is echoed as JSON after the loop. Your inner loop is echoing out the html directly. So the response has html in it followed by JSON, which the client-side code won't handle. Change the inner `echo` to be `$data['info'] .= '<div>...</div>'` and see what happens.

Comment: Why not query all the artists at once?

Comment: is that actual single part of code? :-/ I mean this does shown code has hidden/cutted parts, except cutted sql-query?

Comment: |nnnnnn done, (with the first one), with the second one I think something is missing to work.     |||    Jakub, Sincerly I don't know how. I know that we need a loop to bring them all, but I dont know how to bring them all at once. ¿Do you mean that is there a way to bring all data in one shot in the inner loop and then build an object for each one? As it looks like in the image linked in the post.    |||   Wizard, yes, it is a single part, I dont want to bother you all putting all, just the language, because the other code is customizable and I think that is another theme. thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually an answer, but some of my suggestions/advices.

First of all code logic is partially not understandable, some variables appears from nowhere. For example: `$i` and `$artists`.
Next one - why do you need to return an html-code instead of pure-data?
Third, subjective on me I guess, that the access to the mysql every time is a bad idea.
My vision looks like that:

> *notice: I haven't test this*

```
<?php

$data = array();
$data['info'] = array(); // changes
$rol = $_POST['id'];

if (isset($_POST['id'])){
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=ec;host=localhost;port=3306';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $options = array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    );

    try {
        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);   } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Fallo conexión: '. $e->getMessage();
        die(); // added
    }

    // what data gets from database?.. idk
    // it seems like companies .. what / why / where it used in this code ? unknown
    // what is $i ? I guess - artist_id
    $sql = "SELECT ....WHERE artist.artist_id = :artist_id";
    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':artist_id', $i, \PDO::PARAM_INT); // suggestion
    $query->execute();
    $companies = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // from where we have got this ?
    if (isset($countries)){

        // 1- This is the First loop, it looks for the artist. This is working, barely.

        $artist_ids = array();
        // from where this too ? okay, just use it
        foreach($artists as $art) {
            $artist = array();

            // it's just a suggestion about your table scheme
            $artist_id = $art['artist_id'];
            $artist_ids[] = $artist_id;

            $artist['name'] = $art['artist_name'];
            $artist['visited_places'] = array();
            $data['info'][$artist_id] = $artist;
        }

        // here is not an actual sql-query, I suggest that country data and artists data are separated
        // and sql must be modified to get data from both table at once
        $sql = 'select country_name, country_city, country_time, artist_id from country join ... where ... and artist_id in ('.implode(',',$artist_ids).')';
        $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        // I don't know how many rows it will be
        // make this safer, get row by row
        while ($row = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $artist_id = $row['artist_id']; // according the new query
            $place = array();
            $place['country'] = $row['country_name'];
            $place['city'] = $row['country_city'];
            $place['time'] = $row['country_time'];
            $data['info'][$artist_id]['visited_places'][] = $place;
        }
    } // if $countries
    // send back pure-data, your javascript can do anything
    echo JSON_encode($data);
} // if $_POST['id']
```

after all your front-end javascript application will receive a JSON-string, something like this: `{"info":{"110":{"name":"Michael Jackson","visited_places":[{"country_name":"JP","country_city":"Tokyo","country_time":"12-sep-1987"},{"country_name":"US","country_city":"New-York","country_time":"03-mar-1988"},{"country_name":"IT","country_city":"Rome","country_time":"23-may-1988"}]}}}`

php source:

```
[info] => Array
    (
        [110] => Array
            (
                [name] => Michael Jackson
                [visited_places] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [country_name] => JP
                                [country_city] => Tokyo
                                [country_time] => 12-sep-1987
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [country_name] => US
                                [country_city] => New-York
                                [country_time] => 03-mar-1988
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [country_name] => IT
                                [country_city] => Rome
                                [country_time] => 23-may-1988
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: My friend, I already made the corrections that you just told me, thank you very much. About $i you where right, it is the "artist_id". About returning html, we need that each object created by the loop for each row has the format as do in the picture, or that was our intention, we don't know how to improve it, or if this is the way it should be done.. ¿It is easier to use arrays, in this case $place, to list countries as in the picture in the post?

Comment: In: " $data['info'][$artist_id]['visited_places'][] = $place; " ¿All information would be stored ? So... ¿Can I make two multi-dimentional arrays and to call the first one in the outer loop and the second one in the inner loop, and both variables act like a Global Variables?

Comment: @DevelopersFortheWorld You can format your html inside your js-application as you wish, for example: `... var el = document.createElement('div'); el.className='MainResult'; el.innerHTML=data['info'][artist_id].name;.. etc`, where `data` is parsed received json from server. The `data-variable` is only the example for more clear understanding, ofc inside the loop it will looks like `item.name` or something similar. You can represent your data as you wish. About `place`-item, you can store all the information from database-row, but in this example it stores only `name, city and time`.